# Php undefined constant bd

Tags: php

```
<?php

    if(!empty($_POST)){
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];

        include('Validate.php');

        $flag_error = false;
        $errors = array ('username' => array (false,'username incorrecto.'),'Password' => array (false,'Password tem de conter pelo menos 8 caracteres.'));


    /*if(!checkusername($username)){
        $errors['username'][0] = true;
        $flag_error=true;

    }

    if(!Valid_Pass($Password)){
        $errors['Password'][0]=true;
        $flag_error=true;

    }*/

    if(!$flag_error){

        include('bd.inc.php');
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `Utilizadores` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `Password` = '$Password'";
        $verificar=mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

        if (mysql_num_rows($verificar)==true){
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header('Location: index.php');
        }else{
            echo '<font color="red"> Esta conta não existe. </font></a>';   
        }

    }   
}
?>
```

I got this code, and its giving me this error on the browser:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant bd - assumed 'bd' in /home/claire/public_html/login.php on line 8 Notice: Use of undefined constant inc - assumed 'inc' in /home/claire/public_html/login.php on line 8 Notice: Use of undefined constant php - assumed 'php' in /home/claire/public_html/login.php on line 8 Warning: require_once(bdincphp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/claire/public_html/login.php on line 8 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'bdincphp' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/claire/public_html/login.php on line 8

Comment: Show us what in `bd.inc.php` please.

Comment: The code you've pasted isn't the code you're running judging by `Warning: require_once(bdincphp): failed to open stream`. Could you have another look and confirm?

Comment: `Warning: require_once(bdincphp): failed to open stream` suggests he's trying to include a file without quotes, and it's attempting to concatenate what it assumes are constants.

Comment: Whats in login.php line 8? I think @iamgory has right.

Comment: @iamgory later I saw, that is from the error message. My bad

Answer (score 2):

this is really your code in the paste? this error is caused you're missing the '

```
include(bd.inc.php);
```

but in the paste, isn't missing.

Comment: there are the `'` signs as I see.

Comment: I think he's right - the error message makes no sense in relation to the provided code example, especially since line 8 is blank.

Comment: php -r 'include(bd.inc.php);' <<< run this in terminal and produces the same error reported. :)

Comment: Actually that gives `Warning: include(): Failed opening 'bdincphp' for inclusion`. He's using `require_once` (Yet more proof the question doesn't contain the correct code)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot quotes around a file name. It should read:

```
include 'bd.inc.php';
```

but it is `include(bd.inc.php);`.

Because it does not start with `$` and it is not a PHP keyword, PHP thinks that `bd` is a constant. And because it cannot find it (because there no `bd` constant declared in the code) it displays the notice and converts it to a string. The same for the other two components. In the end, the erroneous line of code turns into `include 'bdincphp';` and it throws the Fatal error because it cannot find the (non-existing) file.

And you didn't post the file with the error but a different one that doesn't have it. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Error messages suggest missing quotes around a filename in an require_once instruction in the file /home/claire/public_html/login.php on line 8, but on this line there is no require_once instruction, I think you have pasted the wrong file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're including a file in login.php that can't be loaded. 
Try adding ' in login.php require_once function on line 8

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided is not actually the code giving you an error, as referenced by your codebase having `include` and your error having `require_once`.

Regardless, you're attempting to include a file without surrounding the filename with quotes, causing PHP to assume the filename is a list of concatenated constants. Simply change line 8 - which you haven't even given us, and I would assume is `require_once bd.inc.php;` - to -

```
require_once 'bd.inc.php';
```

The error messages will magically disappear.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    if(!empty($_POST)){
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];

        require_once ('Validate.php');
        $flag_error = false;
        $errors = array ('username' => array (false,'username incorrecto.'),'Password' => array (false,'Password tem de conter pelo menos 8 caracteres.'));


    /*if(!checkusername($username)){
        $errors['username'][0] = true;
        $flag_error=true;

    }

    if(!Valid_Pass($Password)){
        $errors['Password'][0]=true;
        $flag_error=true;

    }*/

    if(!$flag_error){

        require_once ('ligacao.php');
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `Utilizadores` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `Password` = '$Password'";
        $verificar=mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

        if (mysql_num_rows($verificar)==true){
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header('Location: index.php');
        }else{
            echo '<font color="red"> Esta conta não existe. </font></a>';   
        }

    }   
}
?>
```

i changed the file name, now it doesnt have the inc name, and also changed the include to require_once, its giving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!$flag_error){

        require_once 'ligacao.php';
        $query = "SELECT * FROM 'username' WHERE 'username' = '$username' AND 'password' = '$password'";
        $verificar=mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

        if (mysql_num_rows($verificar)==true){
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header('Location: index.php');
        }else{
            echo '<font color="red"> Esta conta não existe. </font></a>';   
        }

    }
```

i have this code and its giving me this error: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''username' WHERE 'username' = 'ritasoares' AND 'password' = '12345678'' at line 1